# Passing Script to Msys like sh.exe

Tags: mingw

I have a project that needs to rsync. I have the following code in my script...

```
"C:\Program Files\Git\bin\sh.exe" "<locationto>\git.sh"
"C:\MinGW\msys\1.0\msys.bat" "<locationto>\rsync.sh"
```

I am doing this because I need rsync and the Git version installed doesn't have it. The first command executes fine but the msys.bat doesn't seem to accept the param.

Is there a way I can force MSys to work the same way as sh.exe?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved this the following way

1. Copy msys.bat to msys2.bat
2. Edit msys2.bat

To do this change...

> :startsh if NOT EXIST %WD%sh.exe goto notfound
>       start %WD%sh --login -i  exit

To

> :startsh if NOT EXIST %WD%sh.exe goto notfound start %WD%sh --login -i
>   -c "/c/[location]/rsync.sh" exit

Finally you run the msys2.bat instead.